# Sorting array's objects depending on they array

Tags: javascript, arrays

It might seem confusing, but let me explain:

```js
var a = [
  {
    id: 1,
    sortingArray: [2, 1, 1, 1]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    sortingArray: [2, 1, 2]
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    sortingArray: [2, 1, 1, 2]
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    sortingArray: [2, 3, 1]
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    sortingArray: [2, 2]
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    sortingArray: [2, 3, 2]
  }
]
```

The desired method is this: loop through every item of array a, and loop through the items sortingArrays. I can imagine the working method this way: loop through the a's elements, then check the first item of they sortingArrays. Every item is equivalent, because the every item's first item of sortingArray is 2.

Then, loop through every item's second item of sortingArray. Here, the situation is different, because the sortings must change. Id 1, 2, 3 remains they original place, but id 4, and id 5 changes places. Then, go to the third element of every element's sortingArray. Here, the id 2, and 3 changes places, because the third item of id: 3's sortingArray is 1, while the id: 2's third item of sortingArray is 2.

Here's one important thing. The id: 5's sortingArray don't have a third item. That means it's 100% that the id: 5 will finishes at fourth place. Then comes the 4th item of sortingArray. Both id: 2, 4, and 6 don't have fourth item, so they will remain on they places. The id: 1, and id: 2 also remains it's places because they are already in the right place. And the loop finishes, because the Math.max of every item's sortingArray.length is 4 (because of id: 1, and id: 3).

So the expected result is this:

```js
    var a = [
      {
        id: 1,
        sortingArray: [2, 1, 1, 1]
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        sortingArray: [2, 1, 1, 2]
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        sortingArray: [2, 1, 2]
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        sortingArray: [2, 2]
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        sortingArray: [2, 3, 1]
      },
      {
        id: 6,
        sortingArray: [2, 3, 2]
      }
    ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check every item of the arrays and return the final delta of the values.

> This solution features the standard sorting callback of
>
> ```
> (a, b) => a - b
> ```
>
> which takes a numerical value of `a` and `b` and returns the delta of it.
>
> This idea is taken for arrays of numbers and iterates the arrays and takes the delta for each index and assigns the delta to `d`.
>
> [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) iterates until a [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value is returned. The return value here is the delta. That means, any uero value leads to a further iteration of the arrays until a non zero value is found (or the array has no more values).
>
> Finally, the last delta is returned.

```js
var array = [{ id: 1, sortingArray: [2, 1, 1, 1] }, { id: 2, sortingArray: [2, 1, 2] }, { id: 3, sortingArray: [2, 1, 1, 2] }, { id: 4, sortingArray: [2, 3, 1] }, { id: 5, sortingArray: [2, 2] }, { id: 6, sortingArray: [2, 3, 2] }]

array.sort(({ sortingArray: a }, { sortingArray: b }) => {
    var d;
    a.some((v, i) => d = v - b[i]);
    return d;
});

console.log(array);
```

If needed, you could normalize the arrays to the same length.

```js
var array = [{ id: 1, sortingArray: [2, 1, 1, 1] }, { id: 2, sortingArray: [2, 1, 2] }, { id: 3, sortingArray: [2, 1, 1, 2] }, { id: 4, sortingArray: [2, 3, 1] }, { id: 5, sortingArray: [2, 2] }, { id: 6, sortingArray: [2, 3, 2] }]

array.sort(({ sortingArray: a }, { sortingArray: b }) => {
    var d;

    while (a.length < b.length) a = a.concat(0);
    while (b.length < a.length) b = b.concat(0);
    a.some((v, i) => d = v - b[i]);
    return d;
});

console.log(array);
```

Comment: Sorry Nina, your answer perfectly solves my problem, it works, everything's fine, but i don't completely understand it. If you have time for that, can you explain what's happening here more deep?

Comment: Brilliant method. Really.